# Multiclass generic collection in C#

Tags: java, c#, generics, wildcard

I need a typesafe multitype collection, e.g., a map that maps from a generic tag class `Tag<T>` to an object of type `T`. In Java, I would have written something like this:

```
class ClassMap {
    private HashMap<Tag<?>,?> map = new HashMap<>();

    <T> void put(Tag<T> tag, T value){
        map.put(tag,value);
    }

    <T> get(Tag<T> tag){
        return (T) map.get(tag);
    }
}
```

The collection is type safe, i.e., the cast `(T)` will always succeed as the collection checks that the class corresponds to the tag on insertion.

But how to do this in C#? Afaik, there are no wildcards in C#, so I cannot write `HashMap<Tag<?>,?>` here. How can I tell C# that I need a generic map but cannot exactly specify its parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this? All classes of `C#` are derived from `object`.

**EDIT**: Object class reference -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx

You can typecast any object to `object` type -

```
    class Tag<T>{

    }
    class ClassMap {
        private Dictionary<object, object> map = new Dictionary<object,object>();

        public void put<T>(Tag<T> tag, T value){
            map.Add(tag, value);
        }

        public T get<T>(Tag<T> tag){
            return (T)map[tag];
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassMap v = new ClassMap();
            Tag<Int16> t = new Tag<short>();
            v.put<short>(t, 10);
            var tt = v.get<short>(t);
        }
    }
```

The debug info -

[image]

Comment: That seems to do what I want! So does this hold in general: Whenever I need a class field that would have had wildcards if I had written it in Java, I need to replace all wildcard'd types with object (or another non-generic base class) and cast back once I need them?

Comment: Yes, this will work in general. However you should worry about the performance, typecasting to and from `object` is a heavy operation and should be avoided as much as you can.

Comment: Great, thank you! Edit: Well, if it is such a performance hit, are there better ways to maintain collections where various types may be mixed? I see none.

Comment: I am afraid not, but there are architecture changes that you can do so that you do not need object type conversion. You can try other design patters like - IOC , Service Locator patterns etc.